# Hive version compatible with Spark

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Everyday I get more and more confused. I am learning to use spark with hive and every tutorial I find on the internet vaguely explains the relationship First of all what does it mean when people say `hive compatible with spark`.I downloaded prebuilt spark and it's version is 2.1.1 and I downloaded hive 2.1.1. My goal is to access hive metastore from spark but everytime I run spark query I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Which according [this website](https://discourse.looker.com/t/fixing-spark-default-metastore-and-hive-metastore-mismatch-issues-prior-to-looker-3-44/2123)

> If you have a metastore version mismatch, either or both of the last two SQL statements will result in this error message: Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (state=,code=0)

Where I am confused is when people say hive spark compatibility do they mean spark version and hive version? which in my case both are 2.1.1 ( yet I am getting this error) or they mean `metastore database schema version and hive-metastore jar version inside spark/jars folder`?

Now my hive metastore-schema version is 2.1.0 and I have `hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar`, So do I need to change hive-metastore-schema version to 1.2.1 ? According to [this website](https://community.mapr.com/community/exchange/blog/2017/06/19/handling-hive-metastore-db-table-version-inconsistency-when-hive-client-uses-embedded-metastore)

> For handling Spark 2.1.0, which is currently shipped with Hive 1.2 jar, users need to use a Hive remote metastore service (hive.metastore.uris), where metastore service is started with hive.metastore.schema.verification as TRUE for any Spark SQL context. This will force the Spark Client to talk to a higher version of the Hive metastore (like Hive 2.1.0), using lower Hive jars (like Hive 1.2), without modifying or altering the existing Hive schema of the metastore database.

I do have `hive-schema-verification set to true` and still get same error.Also please take your time to check [spark-website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore), where they say

> spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 1.2.1  ( Version of the Hive metastore. Available options are 0.12.0 through 1.2.1.)

.Wrapping up my question, my goal is to     1) understand meaning behind `hive compatible with spark`                      2) connect to hive metastore using spark
Please try to elaborate your answer or be kind to provide me link where I can find my answers. I am genuingly confused.

Comment: I have the similar issue in Drill. How did you solve that? I suppose you have specified the path to hive-metastore-2.1.1.spark2.jar

Answer (score 1):

Hive with Spark: If you get metastore version related errors, The following meta store jar and version should be set in spark defaults.conf or passed on submit, each conf is separate parameter
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=/home/hadoopuser/hivemetastorejars/* 
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3.0